# Libertinus, backslash in text

Tags: libertine, libertinus

Does libertinus/libertine just not have a textmode backslash character? 
(That character must be in the font somewhere, is there a way to access it?)

Minimum working example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{libertine} % Pretty much same thing if replaced by libertinus

\begin{document}
Normal text.

Backslash: \textbackslash. 

Try to type the code: \verb|\textbackslash|.
\end{document}
```

Output (note that the backslash character is replaced by quotation mark):

[image]

`pdflatex` log. Note that `\textbackslash` is undefined and a substitute from CM is used.

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Arch Linux) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./lib.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/standalone/standalone.cls
Document Class: standalone 2018/03/26 v1.3a Class to compile TeX sub-files stan
dalone
...
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/standalone/standalone.cfg)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
...
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/libertine/libertine.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.def
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.dfu)))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mweights/mweights.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontaxes/fontaxes.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/libertine/LinLibertine_I.tex)) (./lib.aux)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/libertine/OT1LinuxLibertineT-TLF.fd)

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OMS/LinuxLibertineT-TLF/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `OMS/cmsy/m/n' instead
(Font)              for symbol `textbackslash' on input line 8.

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/libertine/OT1LinuxLibertineMonoT-TLF.fd)
[1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./lib.aux)

LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.

 ){/usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/libertine/lbtn_3dk467.enc}{/usr/share/
texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/libertine/lbtn_oexx6f.enc}</usr/share/texmf-dist/fon
ts/type1/public/libertine/LinLibertineMT.pfb></usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/type1
/public/libertine/LinLibertineT.pfb></usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/a
msfonts/cm/cmsy10.pfb>
Output written on lib.pdf (1 page, 110075 bytes).
Transcript written on lib.log.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LaTeX does warn you:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OMS/LinuxLibertineT-TLF/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `OMS/cmsy/m/n' instead
(Font)              for symbol `textbackslash' on input line 8.
```

There are not many good reasons to use the legacy OT1 encoding these days. with T1 you get no warning and a `\`

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine} % Pretty much same thing if replaced by libertinus

\begin{document}
Normal text.

Backslash: \textbackslash. 

Try to type the code: \verb|\textbackslash|.
\end{document}
```

Comment: D'oh!  (Should've thought of that myself...)